# My large pine tree is indenting at the bottom of the trunk

Tags: trees, diagnosis, diseases

My large pine tree is starting to indent near the ground. The bark in some spots can be pulled off easily. The pine tree is the type that branches out. What could the issue be ?

Comment: How about a picture to help us identify the problem?

Comment: Definitely need PICTURES!!  Please send closeups as well of the trunk and soil connection!!  How long have you had this tree, did you plant it, what are your watering schedules, where do you live...close ups of foliage as well.  Can you tell if the trunk is clear of all soil, mulch and only the roots are in the ground?  If the trunk is buried under any soil/mulch the cambium stays wet (vascular system just under the bark), bacteria start eating/decomposing and can easily girdle a tree, killing the vascular system and slowly but surely the tree dies.